# New SSL Cert now showing up for Postfix in browser (Ubuntu, Namecheap)

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, ssl-certificate, email-server, ssl-certificate-renewal

I'm a newbie trying to wing it after our Sys Admin left. I needed to update our wildcard certificate and copy it onto our mail server.

I renewed the cert at Namecheap, downloaded it, and installed it on our webservers. Everything is showing up fine in a browser for websites. However, when navigating to the browser portal of our mail server, it is still showing the old cert. I have restarted Postfix, but nothing has changed.

In my /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/wc2_mydomain.com.combined.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/wc2_mydomain.com.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

However, in the browser, it still shows the old expiration date even after `postfix reload` (it should be 2022):

```
Issued On   Wednesday, February 20, 2019 at 6:00:00 PM
Expires On  Saturday, February 20, 2021 at 5:59:59 PM
```

What am I missing? It's going to be very bad if this doesn't show up correctly come Saturday at 6:00pm.

Comment: What is "the browser portal of our mail server"?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Instead of a client (e.g. Thunderbird), going to mail-server-hostname.mydomain.com/mail. The RoundCube web interface.

Comment: It looks like you bound the new certificate to SMTP on the mail server but it doesn't seem like you've bound it to the web server on your mail server.

Comment: Yes, that's what it sounds like.

Comment: @joeqwerty Going to do some research to see how to do that. Will come back with my results unless someone chimes in. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: Welp, thought I would try and restart apache and that was a mistake. Now I can't even access my webmail dashboard. Connection refused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was on the right track. My `/etc/ssl/certs/wc2_mydomain.com.combined.crt` file was simply out of order. I discovered the correct order [in this article (at the bottom)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssl-library-error-185073780-key-values-mismatch)

It states:

```
and the correct way is this:

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certificate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
```

I simply had my certs out of order! :D My browser interface works, and the cert shows expiring 2022. Thanks for the nudges in the right direction friends. Another crisis averted.